# Question closed by myself returns in audit

Tags: bug, review-audit

Today in review queue I received a question looking very familiar. After I voted to close it, my deja vu was confirmed: I already voted to close this question, quite recently. Do such audits make any sense?

[image]

Comment: The point of the audits is in part to make sure you're not robo-reviewing, so it shouldn't matter that you're being presented with a post that you had closed/deleted/flagged.